# Gitignore not working. Do I have the wrong file path?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
backend
 - node_modules
 - app.js
.gitignore
```

My `.gitignore` file looks like this:

```
./backend/node_modules
```

But for some reason my `node_modules` folder is still getting uploaded to Github. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: `.gitignore` has no effect in terms of _pushing_. You can't just ignore what is already part of a commit (and therefore, _pushed_). If the files are already _tracked_, the file does not affect them. Are they tracked already in the branch? If they are, then you need to remove them (either going forward, and keeping them in history... or rewriting history to remove them from past history).

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring a file changes using `.gitignore` works only when the file is never tracked(aka never added to git using git add).

If you want to delete the changes on remote altogether, update .gitignore with exclusion and execute following command

```
git rm -r --cached ./backend/node_modules
```

If you simply want to exclude pushing changes but don't want to delete node modules on remote, you can ask git to assume the above path as unchanged by below command

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged ./backend/node_modules
```